# Unable to implement Feature folders in asp.net core 2.0 Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-core

I am trying to implement Feature folders in Core 2.0 web app using the package OdeToCode.AddFeatureFolders. 
Screenshots and code snippets are as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below are the 2 classes I have used to implement feature folders functionality:

```
namespace FeatureWebApp.Infrastructure.FeatureFolders
   {
    public class FeatureViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
     {
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(
        ViewLocationExpanderContext context,
        IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (viewLocations == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewLocations));
        }

        // {0} - Action Name
        // {1} - Controller Name
        // {2} - Area name

        //Features
        yield return "/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml";

        yield return "/Features/{2}/{0}.cshtml";

        yield return "/Features/{1}/{2}/{0}.cshtml";

        yield return "/Features/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml";

        //Feature Areas
        yield return "/Features/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
        yield return "/Features/{2}/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml";
        yield return "/Features/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml";

        //Shared
        yield return "/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml";

    }
 }
 }


   namespace FeatureWebApp.Infrastructure.FeatureFolders
   {
    public static  class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
     public static IMvcBuilder AddFeatureFolders(this IMvcBuilder services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        services.AddRazorOptions(o =>
        {
            o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new FeatureViewLocationExpander());
        });

        return services;
    }
 }
}
```

Startup .cs:-

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {

        services.AddMvc().AddFeatureFolders();
       }
```

The problem here is unless I write [Route("CreditCardAPI")]in creditcardapi controller I am not able to call CreditCardAPI methods directly using "http:localhost:00000/CreditCardAPI".It shows me error
"No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:61452/CreditCardAPI"

I have already written [Area("CreditCards")] above CreditCardAPI controller as shown in image above. Where as in Home controller I haven't declared any area or any route still I can call home controller methods(default index method) directly without ant area or route declaration.

[image]

Also if I use nested folder structure like ->Features ->TroubleTickets ->List-> Controller,view,model related to List, as shown in above image, how can I call CreditCardAPI controller methods in this case?

Any suggestions or ideas? Any steps I am missing here?

Comment: Where's your route config? If you don't supply a custom Route Handler, you have to specify the route as attribute

Comment: Is it very necessary to write a custom Route Handler in  route config file to route to a particular controller while implementing feature folders? As we have already written FeatureViewLocationExpander class for this.

Comment: no! but you have to configure at least the route paths correctly, to support such complexity

Comment: Cant we do this without configure route paths just with the help of FeatureViewLocationExpander class? As  FeatureViewLocationExpander  class is mainly used here for configuring routes and simplify the complex folder structure routing.I dont want to use explicit route configuration. Any other method or way to achieve this?

Comment: As the name say: FeatureViewLocationExpander to provide custom locations for your views, instead of the default VIew folder. Routes are completely different subject.

Comment: OK.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: are you using OdeToCode.AddFeatureFolders?

Answer (score 2):

The package OdeToCode.AddFeatureFolders  has some conventions for namespaces of controllers.

See the sample app.
https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders/blob/master/sample/WebApplication/Features/Bar/HomeController.cs

```
AddFeatureFolders uses the namespace of the controller to figure out where the views are.
```

The error you have does not indicate a missing view but it might still be related to the namespace of your controller. Please show the complete controller code